How I can make SAM Listen to the same network as docker-compose.yml?
I am implementing an AWS lambda and I launch it locally using aws SAM:
I use the following template.yaml:
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  TechMate Internal API

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60

Parameters:
  Table:
    Type: String
    Default: Activities
  Region:
    Type: String
    Default: eu-west-2
  AWSEnv:
    Type: String
    Default: AWS

Resources:
  CreateActivityFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: myapp
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DYNAMO_DB_REGION: localhost
          DYNAMO_DB_ENDPOINT: http://localhost:8000
          DYNAMO_DB_KEY: local
          DYNAMO_DB_SECRET: local
          CHATBOT_API_KEY: CHATBOT_API_KEY
          CHATBOT_API_SECRET: CHATBOT_API_SECRET
      Events:
        CreateActivities:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: post
     
  
Outputs:
  ActivitiesApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Create Activity Function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/activities/"

And I use the follοwing command to launch it:
sam local start-lambda

But my dev environment I use the following config:
version: "3.8"
name: ${APP_NAME}
services:

  # PHP APPS
  php_app:
    container_name: ${APP_NAME}
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/Dockerfile
      args:
        - COMPOSER_VERSION=latest
        - XDEBUG_VERSION=latest
        - PHP_VERSION=8.3
    volumes:
      - "php_app:/var/www/html"
    networks:
      private:
    env_file: env/php.env

  # Supportive services
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    networks:
      private:
      public:
        ipv4_address: ${IP_BASE}.2
    volumes:
      - "php_app:/var/www/html"
      - "./conf/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro"
      - "./ssl/certs/www.crt:/etc/nginx/ssl/www.crt:ro"
      - "./ssl/certs/www.key:/etc/nginx/ssl/www.key:ro"

  # Rest of services Here    

volumes:

  php_app:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: ${PHP_APP_PATH}
  

networks:
  private:
  public:
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: ${IP_BASE}.0/24
          gateway: ${IP_BASE}.1

How I can make sam running lambda and its emulated Gateway to listen upon private network in my docker-compose?

I found no way to make sam listen into same network defined upon docker-compose.yml but I followed this approach using these steps:
Step1 Make sam listen into all network interfaces
An Approach I followed is to run the following command at my host:
sam local start-api --host=0.0.0.0

It can be better refined but in my case works fine and I am ok with that.
STEP 2 define the host ip upon docker-compose
Approach 1 Detect IP using ip or parsing /proc/route
For this you can use either the ip command:
ip route | grep default | awk '{print $3}'

Or if using php you can also use the following script:
https://github.com/pc-magas/docker_php_dev/blob/master/utils/get_xdebug_ip
Both script or command must run INSIDE the docker container. Usually I run these commands upon docker's entrypoint script.
Approach 2 Use host.docker.internal (easier one)
Docker desktop allows to access host listening services via host.docker.internal domain. But upon linux is not defined.
For that define upon your service:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

And the api will be accessible via:
curl host.docker.internal:3000

